# How to access the default icons folder from code in Android?

Tags: android, icons

How do you use the default Android icons in your projects? Do you have to copy them manually? I found just a part of them in @android:drawable/, but those weren't the ones I need.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have to copy them manually?

Yes.

> I found just a part of them in @android:drawable/, but those weren't the ones I need.

The rest are not part of the Android SDK in terms of the public API.